# Strong equality

Tags: javascript, jquery

You have been instructed to test the value of the variable shown below:

```
var length = "50";
```

You then write the following code:

```
if (length === 50)
```

Which of the following is the purpose of this line of code?

`A.` It prevents a block of code from firing if the length equals 50, and the data type is integer.

`B.` It prevents a block of code from firing if the length equals 50, and the data type is string.

`C.` It allows for a block of code to fire if the length equals 50 regardless of the data type.

`D.` It allows a block of code from firing if the length equals 50 depending on the data type.

Can I have answer for the above ?

`My Answer is D`.But it says it wrong.What yours ?

Comment: You seem to be implying that you don't know the answer. So what have you tried in order to find out?

Comment: A few lines of basic JavaScript should give you the answer.

Comment: @David my answer is D.What yours ?

Comment: JavaScript can fire code? What sorcery is this?

Comment: @Sampath I think it's either A, B or C. Definitely!

Comment: @phant0m this is a exam 70-480 question.

Comment: @user1479606 Nope.Can It have only 1 answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var myInteger = 50;

if(myInteger === 50) {
  alert("Matched integer");
}

if(myInteger === "50") {   
  alert("Matched string version of integer");
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/8RdLK/

Only the first `if` block matches, so the answer is D.

Comment: Yes my answer is also D.But solution is giving as C by "Actual Exams" ?

Comment: [ECMAScript Specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.9.6): **If Type(x) is different from Type(y), return false.** [From MDN, in more human language](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators): **A strict comparison (e.g. ===) is only true if the operands are the same Type.** I can't comment on why an examiner would think differently.

Comment: Yes you're write.But Do you have any sense about or explanation about answer C ? Why they gave it as ans ?

Comment: @Sampath: The only reasonable explanation is, the question was mistyped.  The difference between `==` and `===` is the very difference between C and D.